# Chrome extension how to use lists/arrays?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to develop a small extension that is supposed to let the user add URLs and whenever the browser goes to one of the added URLs, it will do something.

Now I have looked at the official getting started guide so I got some of the basics down. However, I don't understand how I can store a list and update it and check it. Under conditions, I would like to iterate my list and then check if any of the values there actually match. Something like this:

**background.js**

```js
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

'use strict';
        
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var testArray=["Installed1", "Installed2"];
        
  chrome.storage.sync.set( { list:testArray }, function() {
    console.log("added to list");
  });
        
  chrome.storage.sync.get('list', function(data) {

    changeColor.style.backgroundColor = data.color;
    changeColor.setAttribute('value', data.color);
              
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {

      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com'},
        })],//Check the list values here?
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);

    });

  });
                  
});
```

Comment: The question is too vague currently. There are several solutions depending on what exactly needs to be done.

Comment: I am sure there are. I basically want a list with CRUD operations on.

Comment: "CRUD" is also a vague term that can be solved via many methods in the extensions API. Could you give a specific example of the actions you want to perform?

Comment: Sure. I want to initialize a default list on startup. Then in the options of the extension I want to add urls to this list. Then everytime you navigate to a new url, it should be checked against the list to see if it is there.

Comment: You've just repeated your question, but it's still unclear what actions you want to perform on the URLs. Thing is, with declarativeContent (or several other API) you can register a listener to run on the URLs from the list so there's no need to check if the URL is there because it will be there. The point I'm trying to get across is that you need to describe the actions that will be performed on a URL from that list.

Comment: Well, I want to just check if the current URL exists in the option list. If it does exist I just want to log it to the console.

Comment: Okay, this is my last attempt to clarify the question. What is "current URL"? Is it the URL of the active tab? Do you want to check it every time the user switches tabs? And logging it isn't your real purpose of the extension, right? So what will you do when the URL matches? For example, maybe access the page contents?

Comment: Aha yes it would be the current URL. No I don't need to access the contents of the page at all. How does it matter what I want to do when there is a match? Am I not able to code anything I want there anyway?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do when a URL matches, a different API should be used. Since you didn't clarify the question I can only mention the most popular approaches: chrome.tabs.onUpdated event and chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted event.